# SSRS split/alignment on single textbox

Tags: reporting-services

I have one text box that is populated with individual sentences on each line of the text box. The text box looks like this on the report:

Green Berber Carpet   $2,000.34

Yellow Paint   $500.00

Samsung TV with DVR $450.00

I need to align the description left and have the amount right aligned.
My dilemma is that the description and amount are not two different fields.I have tried the split function but it is only doing the first line of the textbox. Is it possible to split the string into two fields and make each have their own alignment AND each line of the text box be altered in that manner?